# What are these SDActivityAdvertiser processes in my Mac OSX system log

Tags: logging, console, system, console.log

I checked my console app and found many of these entries in my log:

```
17:20:24.680 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (com.apple.identityservices.error-Fehler 200.))
```

By many, I mean about 30 in the last 3 minutes. Somebody know what's this all about?

Comment: In the General pane of System Preferences, uncheck the box marked          `Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices`

Comment: @ineersa please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the General pane of System Preferences, uncheck the box marked Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices